# Why does my output include "None" at the end?

Tags: python

I just started learning coding and I made this quiz.

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer

question_prompts = [
    "What is 9 + 10?\n (a)21\n (b)19\n (c)12\n\n",
    "What color is an apple?\n (a)12\n (b)red\n (c)blue hehehe\n\n",
    "What color is a zebra?\n (a)Black\n (b)White\n (c)Red all over\n\n"
]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "b"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "b"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "b")
]

score = 0
for i in range(len(questions)):
    if questions[i].answer == input(print(questions[i].prompt)):
        print("Correct!")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
print("You got " + str(score) + "/3 correct")
```

Whenever I run it, it always prints None at the bottom of the question. Why is this?

```
What is 9 + 10?
 (a)21
 (b)19
 (c)12


None
```

Comment: `input(...)` already has the side-effect of printing something to standard output. When you do `input(print(...))`, you are printing something to standard output via `print`, and then you are printing the return value of `print` to standard output via `input`, which will always be `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You did `input(print(questions[i].prompt))`, but `input`’s parameter is just the prompt as a string (see `help(input)`). You don’t need to `print` it yourself. `print` prints the message, then returns `None`, which `input` uses as the prompt.

```
input(questions[i].prompt)
```